# Contributions of variables to PC in python

Tags: python, plot, bar-chart, pca, feature-extraction

I used PCA to find 60 PC's:

```
N_comp=60 
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
pca = PCA(n_components = N_comp)
X_pca=pca.fit_transform(X_scale) #lower dimension data
eigenvalues=pca.components_
```

Now, I'm trying to find the contributions of my features (the columns of X data) to PC1 and PC2. For example, for PC1, I'd like to show a bar plot of the percentage of each of the top 10 features, where the x-axis would have the labels of the features.

something like this:
[image: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Hz24K.png]

I'm trying to do this in python, but can't figure out how to find the features names. For example what I did is sorting to find the top 10 features variables composing PC1 as:

```
N_elements=10
PC1=abs(eigenvalues[1,:])
PC1.sort(axis=0)
PC1=PC1[::-1]
PC1=PC1[0:N_elements]
PC1
```

Which results in

```
array([0.17040832, 0.16937861, 0.1683676 , 0.16544657, 0.16491703,
   0.16491679, 0.16168056, 0.16108829, 0.16034576, 0.16029183])
```

and plotting it:

```
plt.bar(range(N_elements), PC1, alpha=0.3, align='center')
plt.title('Contributions of variables to PC1')
```

but this results in X-axis of just numbers 0 to 9 (corresponds to 10 elements). How could I retrieve the names and put labels on the plot bar?

[image]

Thanks so much!

Comment: The link you give provides an explicit formula how the contribution in percentage of a variable to the principal component is calculated. Why don't you implement this?

Comment: It looks like you want the `fviz_contrib` function specifically. The page you link to seems to provide a pretty good guide for how to apply it, if you're having a specific problem doing that you should explain more about what you've actually tried and where you're stuck.

Comment: This is a **completely different** question from the one you had originally asked (which had an `r` coding tag, hence the answers given below). It is **very poor form** to completely change the question after 3 hours of inactivity and after having received answers from SO users in response to your original question. It shows disregard of the general SO posting guidelines and disrespect towards the SO community. I vote **against re-opening** this question. Instead, the question should be deleted and OP should consider asking a new question.

Answer (score 2):

The elements of the the principal components are in the same order as your variables. The larger the absolute value of the element with the corresponding index (i = 1 ... p), the greater that variable contributes to the transformation of that PC.

Answer (score 1):

First off, please consider the comments and what you can do to improve on the quality of your question. Critical components of a "good" question around here are (1) reproducible sample data, (2) a genuine code attempt, and (3) a *specific* coding question rather than a post asking "how to implement XYZ".

That aside, the following should get you started. All the information is in fact in the link you yourself provide, I suggest spending some time understanding the material.

1. First off, as you don't provide sample data let's work with the in-built `USArrest` dataset. We perform a PCA using `prcomp`

   ```
   pca <- prcomp(USArrests)
   ```
2. We get the coordinates by multiplying variable loadings and the standard deviation

   ```
   coord <- t(t(pca$rotation) * pca$sdev)
   ```

   The `t(t(...) * ...)` construct here ensures that we multiply entries of every column of the variable loadings matrix `pca$rotation` with the corresponding entry from the vector `pca$sdev`.
3. As explained in the link, the variable contribution are then just the squared coordinates expressed as a percentage of the sum of the squared coordinates per principal component

   ```
   contrib <- t(t(coord ^ 2) / colSums(coord ^ 2)) * 100
   contrib
   #                PC1        PC2        PC3        PC4
   #Murder    0.1739250  0.2008981  0.6382517 98.9869251
   #Assault  99.0465399  0.3452741  0.4565669  0.1516191
   #UrbanPop  0.2147001 95.4250536  4.0218813  0.3383649
   #Rape      0.5648349  4.0287742 94.8833000  0.5230908
   ```
4. Let's compare this with the results from `factoextra::get_pca_var`

   ```
   get_pca_var(pca)$contrib
   #              Dim.1      Dim.2      Dim.3      Dim.4
   #Murder    0.1739250  0.2008981  0.6382517 98.9869251
   #Assault  99.0465399  0.3452741  0.4565669  0.1516191
   #UrbanPop  0.2147001 95.4250536  4.0218813  0.3383649
   #Rape      0.5648349  4.0287742 94.8833000  0.5230908
   ```

   As you can see, results are identical.
   I leave the plotting up to you; you can find plenty of advice regarding how to show a barplot here on SO and on the web.

Comment: @AAA You yourself flagged this with the `r` code tag; now after 3 hours (!!) of your inactivity you're telling us that you're looking for a Python solution? That is extremely poor form and extremely rude towards everyone who has been trying to help you so far. Keep in mind that you are asking strangers on the internet for their free help. This behaviour is not acceptable.

Comment: I appreciate that and agree. It took me time to realize also what I don't understand...

Comment: @MauritsEvers, would you have a similar solution using python? I'm trying to replicate the same thought using python, but I'm unsuccessful.